# Are $(x^3)^{1/3} $ and $\sqrt{x^2}$ monomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology

> Are $(x^3)^{1/3} $ and $\sqrt{x^2}$ monomials?

In mathematics, a [monomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial) is, roughly speaking, a polynomial which has only one term. Two different definitions of a monomial may be encountered:

For the first definition, a monomial, also called power product, is a product of powers of variables with nonnegative integer exponents, or, in other words, a product of variables, possibly with repetitions.

For the second definition, a monomial is a monomial in the first sense multiplied by a nonzero constant, called the coefficient of the monomial.

Comment: How many real polynomials do you know with $P(x)^3=x^3$?

Comment: We know that $(x^3)^{1/3}=x,  \sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Are these monomials?

Comment: Just apply the definition of "monomial".

Answer (score 1):

I would say "it depends."  What sets a monomial apart, in my mind, is not the values it takes (which would make these into monomials, ignoring the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ instead of $x$), but rather the form they are represented in.  So to me, they are not monomials, but rather are functions that are equal to monomials.  However, I don't know that everybody would agree.

To give another example that I do not think of as a monomial, but which others might, consider $x+x^2-x$.  While it is equal to $x^2$, which is a monomial, I don't think of it as a monomial because it has multiple terms.  To me, a monomial must obviously be a monomial because of how it is written.

The question I have is, "What is the context in which the question is important to you?"  That is, are you asking for clarification for the sake of clarification, or is there a specific reason where this matters for you?

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable to interpret them as monomials provided that it is specified what the domain and range of the $n$-th roots are.  Do you want a square or cube root in the realm of (a) monomials with coefficient $1$, (b) monomials with any constant coefficient from a ring $R$, (c) polynomials with all their coefficients in a ring $R$, (d) something else.  The ring $R$ would need to be given as well.

Those choices can make the difference between having zero, one, or multiple roots and which of those count as monomials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the domain of real numbers, then $(x^3)^{1/3} = x^1 = x$ is a monomial. But $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ is not, because it is different from $x^1$, and any other power of $x$.