# Is $\sqrt[3]{x^3}$ monomial?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

I have been confused by different interpretations of polynomial and monomial. Is $\sqrt[3]{x^3}$ really a monomial?

Comment: Isn't it just $x$?

Comment: Or, more generally: what do you mean by $\sqrt[3]{x^3}$? What is the context? Is it a function, like in real analysis, is it an element of some algebraic closure of the field $K(x)$?

Comment: @philomath, yes the result is $x$, but how about the function itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are $(x^3)^{1/3} $ and $\sqrt{x^2}$ monomials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913958/are-x31-3-and-sqrtx2-monomials)

Comment: @PNDas, yes I saw that link before I post my question, but those answers were not approved and that added more confusion.

Comment: @Peter Oh! Okay. You could've said that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of real numbers, yes, this is just $x$, which is a monomial. However--

It's not in the *form* of a monomial, but it is *functionally equivalent* to a monomial in the sense that its values agree everywhere with the monomial $x$.

So I suppose the real answer depends on what your definition of "is" is.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt[3]3$ equals $x$, $\xi x$ or $\xi^2 x$, where $\xi$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity.
If you take the ground field $\Bbb C$ or say $\Bbb R(\xi)$, then all solutions are terms with coefficient and variable $x$. One of it is a monomial: $x$.